# Getting nullpointer exception on Recyclerview when setting layout manager in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**Full error trace:**

```
07-09 15:04:39.552  32410-32410/com.example.junker.lectio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.junker.lectio, PID: 32410
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.junker.lectio.OpgaveFragmentIndhold.onCreateView(OpgaveFragmentIndhold.java:103)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityTh
```

first time using recyclerview and have been fighting this all day.
Have tried a ton of things, moving attaching the recyclerview adapter from on create to oncreateview, making sure i declare a layout manager and checking the code for weird errors.

OpgaveFragmentIndhold

```
public class OpgaveFragmentIndhold extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private RecyclerView rvOpgave;
private RecyclerView.Adapter rvAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment OpgaveFragmentIndhold.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static OpgaveFragmentIndhold newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    OpgaveFragmentIndhold fragment = new OpgaveFragmentIndhold();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public OpgaveFragmentIndhold() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

//Use this part to get the data from lectio and input it here
private ArrayList<Opgave> getOpgaveInfo() {
    ArrayList<Opgave> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    items.add(new Opgave("Opgave titel", "15", "3 dage og 15 timer","link"));
    return items;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_skema, container, false);

    rvOpgave = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.opgave_recycler_view);

    rvAdapter = new OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter(getOpgaveInfo());
    rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());


    rvOpgave.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
    rvOpgave.setAdapter(rvAdapter);




    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter

```
     public class OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Opgave> opgaver;



public OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Opgave> opgaver){
    this.opgaver = opgaver;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView opgaveTitel;
    public TextView opgaveTidspunkt;
    public TextView opgaveUge;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.opgaveTitel =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.opgaveTitel);
        this.opgaveTidspunkt =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.opgaveTidspunkt);
        this.opgaveUge =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.opgaveUge);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    Opgave opgave = opgaver.get(position);
    // Set item views based on the data model
    holder.opgaveTitel.setText(opgave.opgaveTitel);
    holder.opgaveTidspunkt.setText(opgave.opgaveTidspunkt);
    holder.opgaveUge.setText(opgave.opgaveUge);
}

@Override
public OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.opgave_item, parent, false);
    // Return a new holder instance
    return new OpgaveRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);


}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return opgaver.size();
}


}
```

opgave class

```
public class Opgave {

public String opgaveTitel;
public String opgaveUge;
public String opgaveTidspunkt;
public String opgaveId;

public Opgave(String opgaveTitel, String opgaveUge, String opgaveTidspunkt, String opgaveId) {
    this.opgaveTitel = opgaveTitel;
    this.opgaveUge = opgaveUge;
    this.opgaveTidspunkt = opgaveTidspunkt;
    this.opgaveId = opgaveId;
}
}
```

opgave_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/opgave_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/opgaveTitel"
    android:text="titel"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="15"
    android:id="@+id/opgaveUge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="tidspunkt"
    android:id="@+id/opgaveTidspunkt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try inflating `R.layout.opgave_fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inflating wrong xml file.
Change:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_skema, container, false);
```

to

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opgave_fragment, container, false);
```

Comment: god dammit, had to correct it to fragment_opgave_fragment_indhold to be exact. I need to proof read my code better, at least it's super clean now :)